# Change the upload path in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Below code is for uploading file through a form ... I want to change the default upload path for the upload to a folder called abc in the root of my theme.

I hope somebody can help me with this
Below is my code

```
<?php
function upload_user_file( $file = array() ) {

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );

      $file_return = wp_handle_upload( $file, array('test_form' => false ) );

      if( isset( $file_return['error'] ) || isset( $file_return['upload_error_handler'] ) ) {
          return false;
      } else {

          $filename = $file_return['file'];

          $attachment = array(
              'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
              'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
              'post_content' => '',
              'post_status' => 'inherit',
              'guid' => $file_return['url']
          );

          $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_return['url'] );

          require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
          $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
          wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );

          if( 0 < intval( $attachment_id ) ) {
            return $attachment_id;
          }
      }

      return false;
}
?>
```

Form

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['upload']))
    {
       if( ! empty( $_FILES ) ) 
       {
          $file=$_FILES['file'];
          $attachment_id = upload_user_file( $file );

       }
    }
    ?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="upload">
</form>
```

Comment: Take a look at the [upload_dir filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/upload_dir).

Comment: Why do you need it inside your theme folder? Not the best place to upload files. Maybe you could put `abc` inside the uploads folder?